# Cordova fcm notifications work on Android but not on iOS

Tags: cordova, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I followed the following steps for installation:

1. Cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm
2. Added to project root "GoogleService-Info.plist" and "google-services.json"
3. Replaced "GoogleService-Info.plist" inside platforms/ios//resources/resources with the original one. According with known bugs.
4. In my JS, inside deviceready:

   ```
   FCMPlugin.subscribeToTopic('common_topic');

   FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){

   if(data.wasTapped){

     alert( JSON.stringify(data) );

   }else{

     alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
   }

   })
   ```

Now, when I send a notification on android, I see in background and foreground, but in iOS, I don't receive notification at all.

Some configuration missing?

Comment: Do you have the console plugin installed? If so, while your iOS project is running the part of the code you add, is there any error or warning it threw out? And I just check the plugin git hub, it says "Put the downloaded file 'GoogleService-Info.plist' in the Cordova project root folder." Therefore if you replaced the plist file with the original one, there is a chance to miss some configuration there.